# Nesting CompletionStages in Java to make inner blocks run before outer blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, java.util.concurrent

I've written a method like below:

```
 public static CompletionStage<Tuple2<ObjectNode, String>> calculateTemplateTreeAndKeys(
  String content,
  RequestContext context,
  MetricsClient metricsClient,
  JdbcSession jdbcSession) {

AtomicReference<ObjectNode> templateTreeHolder = new AtomicReference<>();
templateTreeHolder.set(Json.rootNode());

return getTemplateIds(context, metricsClient, jdbcSession, content)
    .thenCompose(
        templateIds -> {
          templateIds.map(
              id ->
                  // do something and return CompletionStage<String>
                      .thenAccept(
                          tree -> {
                            templateTreeHolder.set(
                                (ObjectNode)
                                    templateTreeHolder.get().set(id, Json.readTree(tree)));

                            System.out.println(
                                "From inner function: " + templateTreeHolder.get());
                          }));
          return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(NotUsed.getInstance());
        })
    .thenApply(
        notUsed -> {
          String includedTemplateIdsStr =
              getKeysFromTemplateTree(templateTreeHolder.get()).toJavaList().toString();

          System.out.println("From outer function: " + templateTreeHolder.get());

          return Tuple.of(templateTreeHolder.get(), includedTemplateIdsStr);
        });
```

I expect the inner block to process and update templateTreeHolder before 
**.thenApply** is invoked, so that templateTreeHolder would hold correct data to return. But, **.thenApply** block is processing before the inner **.thenAccept** block.

From the console output sequence:

```
From outer function: {}
From inner function: {"f9406341-c62a-411a-9389-00a62bd63629":{}}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong on chaining CompletionStages, kindly advise me how can I make sure that the inner block completes before the outer block?

Comment: Firstly, I think your example is too complex. Secondly, what you are not using any of the `async` methods, why do you even need to do chaining like this?

Comment: @Jai This project is based on event sourcing / CQRS and we need to make sure each event processes before the next one, so intentionally avoided any async methods. I'm confused on why .thenApply runs before .thenAccept and how to avoid that.

Comment: If they need to run sequentially, then simply remove the inner `CompletableFuture`. Wouldn't that be easier? I can't think of any reason how a `CompletableFuture` would do anything useful in a non-asynchronous context.

Comment: @Jai Thanks for the suggestion but that is not possible at the moment, the codebase is bundled with CompletionStages based on Lagom, akka persistence, Vavr libraries. Anyways, it would be helpful if you could suggest something on this exact issue.

Comment: You get exactly what you wish for. The last function is evaluated when `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(NotUsed.getInstance())` has been completed. We can’t know when the function passed to `templateIds.map(…)` is evaluated, as it is entirely unrelated to the rest of your code (especially that chain of completion stages).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Holger, so there is no way to hold the last function till the map returns, is it? Do you have any suggestions to rewrite this part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function passed to `thenCompose` is returning an already complete future, i.e. `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(NotUsed.getInstance());` which allows the dependent stages to proceed immediately. This seem to conflict with the evaluation of the function passed to `templateIds.map(…)`, which happens asynchronously, apparently.

Generally, you should avoid such mixture of completion stages and dependencies to side effects, especially when their asynchronous evaluation is not modeled as prerequisite completion stage.

But you can work-around this, if you have no other choice:

```
return getTemplateIds(context, metricsClient, jdbcSession, content)
    .thenCompose(
        templateIds -> {
          // create an initially uncompleted stage
          CompletableFuture<Object> subStage = new CompletableFuture<>(); 
          templateIds.map(
              id ->
                  // do something and return CompletionStage<String>
                      .thenAccept(
                          tree -> {
                            templateTreeHolder.set(
                                (ObjectNode)
                                    templateTreeHolder.get().set(id, Json.readTree(tree)));

                            System.out.println(
                                "From inner function: " + templateTreeHolder.get());
                            // complete when all work has been done
                            subStage.complete(null);
                          }));
          // use this stage for dependent actions
          return subStage;
        })
    .thenApply(
        notUsed -> {
          String includedTemplateIdsStr =
              getKeysFromTemplateTree(templateTreeHolder.get()).toJavaList().toString();

          System.out.println("From outer function: " + templateTreeHolder.get());

          return Tuple.of(templateTreeHolder.get(), includedTemplateIdsStr);
        });
```

In the code above, the future will never get completed if your action fails with an exception before the completion attempt. The general pattern would be like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Type> stage = new CompletableFuture<>();
…
try {
    code that will eventually call complete on stage
}
catch(Throwable t) {
    stage.completeExceptionally(t);
}
```

But, of course, it will get a bit more complicated when the code supposed to complete the stage also bears asynchronous processing, so you have to guard the code trying to submit the actual completion code, as well as the actual completion code.

So, a more elaborated version of the inner code would look like:

```
CompletableFuture<Object> subStage = new CompletableFuture<>();
try {
    templateIds.map(
        id ->
            // do something and return CompletionStage<String>
            .thenAccept(
                tree -> {
                  templateTreeHolder.set(
                      (ObjectNode)
                          templateTreeHolder.get().set(id, Json.readTree(tree)));

                  System.out.println(
                      "From inner function: " + templateTreeHolder.get());
                })
            .whenComplete((v,t) -> {
                // complete when all work has been done
                if(t != null) subStage.completeExceptionally(t);
                else subStage.complete(v);
            }));
} catch(Throwable t) {
    subStage.completeExceptionally(t);
}
// use this stage for dependent actions
return subStage;
```

(perhaps, the “do something and return CompletionStage” has to be guarded with `try { … } catch(Throwable t) { subStage.completeExceptionally(t); }` too)